# HTML Fieldset content overflows at 100% height (Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fieldset

I have a problem with the HTML `fieldset` element in Chrome.

I want to have a fixed-height `fieldset`, and within it a scrollable `div`. Everything looks fine until I put a `legend` in - when I do so, the `div` spills out from the bottom of the `fieldset`. I also checked in Firefox, and it does not do this (i.e. does exactly what I would expect).

Anyone else seeing this? Is it a Chrome bug? Anyone know if there is a hack for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>a</title>
        <style>
            fieldset {
                height: 80px;
            }
            fieldset div {
                height: 100%;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Test</legend>
            <div>
                Foo!<br/>
                Foo!<br/>
                Foo!<br/>
                Foo!<br/>
                Foo!<br/>
                Foo!<br/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks fine in chrome for me. Btw its `<br />`!

Comment: @DanielB: Doh, of course it is! Sorry, it's late and I'm being retarded; I'll edit it. But it does not change my problem. Tested on Chrome 11.0.696.57 on Ubuntu. I'll see about doing a screenie.

Comment: Test this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCRzJ/) I use Win Chrome 11.0.696.65

Comment: First, jsfiddle removes the default `fieldset` styling, so you have to add `border: 1px solid black` at least, to even notice the effect. It may work on a Win build, but on my Ubuntu I am getting pretty much the same as in the screenshot above (modulo margins, stripped by jsfiddle's reset script).

Comment: I have Windows 7 with Chrome 11.0.696.68 and it looks similar to the screenshot, so I guess it's not the fault of the platform it's released for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, if you do not need to use the `legend` element, is to use an `h1` and style appropriately.  This works for me in both Chrome and FF.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>a</title>
    <style>
        fieldset {
            height: 80px;
        }
            h1 {
                margin:0;
                margin-top:-1em;
                font-size:1em;
                background:white;
                width:33px;
            }   
        fieldset div {
            height: 100%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div>
            Foo!<br/>
            Foo!<br/>
            Foo!<br/>
            Foo!<br/>
            Foo!<br/>
            Foo!<br/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, this hack seems to be exactly what I wanted. Thanks! (actually, I'd prefer `legend` worked as it should, but can't have everything :) )

Comment: On second thought - still not doing everything I want. Having to specify width for the `h1` is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by adding `padding-bottom` to the fieldset for Chrome only.  This balances out some of the extra height %.  It's nice in that it works (relatively consistently) even when resizing.

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome')) { // Replace this with your preferred way of checking userAgent
    $('fieldset').css('padding-bottom', '4%'); // Exact percent may vary
}
```

Just as a note, I found this to be an issue in at least IE8 - IE11 as well, so the fix can be applied to IE.

Answer (score 0):

I see the overflow.

It looks as if the `fieldset div` has too much height applied to it.  Try

```
fieldset div {
            height: 85%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
```

Works for me in Chrome.

Of course, without the code for the legend, I am not sure if there are other issues.

Comment: Of course, reducing the height would work, but then if I resize the `fieldset` it would not do what I want (i.e. always fill the entire inner area of the `fieldset`). Besides, `height: 100%` renders correctly on at least Firefox, so it would fall apart with `85%`. Thus, I can't accept this answer.

Comment: I checked in Firefox 3.6.6 and the same problem occurs at 100%... the `div` overflows the `fieldset`.  However, both Chrome and FF work at 85% for me.

Comment: `85%` "works", just doesn't do what I want. It's kind of like telling a mechanic that your engine hood pops up whenever you speed over 20 km/h, and he tells you that the solution is to only drive very slowly.

Comment: Gotcha.  See another solution below.